# Would it make sense to set an object using an external method? Using this?

Tags: java

Can I use this, or would there be a better way?:

```
public static <T> void setIfNull(T o, T value) {
    if(o == null) {
       o = value;
    }
}
```

**Edit!:** I changed my code (by reading I would only 'set' the local variable):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T set(Class<T> clazz, String path, Object value) {
    T result = null;

    try {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(path);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, value);

        result = (T) field.get(null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Final Edit: I solved the problem, using the code from the 'edit' above.**

Comment: This method doesn't do anything other than change your method's local reference to `o`.

Comment: In simpler terms, setting `o` within the method only sets it within the method.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko He means that this code does not have any effect. Maybe the idea was that "o" would be a static field of the enclosing class. But: even if the enclosing class has a static field "o", then the method parameter "o" is shadowing that. Therefore the above code does only update the parameter o. Thus: this method is a "no op"

Comment: There would be a better way, and it'd be not to use this kind of approach at all, but instead to put the null check directly in where you're using it, and not trying to pull out a method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you actually want to do something like:

```
class Foo {
  private static Bar someStaticField = ...;

  public static setStaticFieldIfNull(Bar newValue) {
      if (someStaticField == null) {
         someStaticField = newValue;
```

Is that what you have in mind?

If so, of course this is possible (and when dropping the static keyword, it will also work for "ordinary" fields).

If so, the whole thing is simply called a "setter" method.

"setters" do have their place in programming (you might want to google this term); but very often, using setters is a "smell" that can indicate a design worth rethinking and changing.

Thus: probably you have some other problem; and you should try to explain the problem you want to solve with the code you put in your question.

Comment: Actually you are very right about my intention. However the only difference  the 'setter' and the 'field' is in two different classes.

Comment: I think the OP version would not work, and it is very different than yours (has a parameter rather than a field). So it may confuse the OP that you're saying "it's possible" and then showing something completely different.

Comment: @Experminator That is why I asked about the problem you want to solve. Using a static method in class A to change a value belonging to some class B is not only "smelling" ... nope, that is straight forward wrong. The whole idea of object oriented programming is: data encapsulation. If some class A has (static) fields, then only methods of class A manipulate those fields.

Answer (score 5):

That won't work because Java is pass-by-value. After the call, `o` still has the same value it had before.

You could make this a method that returns the new value

```
public static <T> T setIfNull(T o, T value) {
    return o == null ? value : o;
}
```

You would have to use it like this

```
o = setIfNull(o, someValue);
```

However, I really don't see the point in this method. I think

```
if (o == null)
    o = value;
```

is simpler and clearer.

Comment: Thank you, but to make clear why I need/want it:  
`InstanceUtil.setIfNull(users, ConfigurationManager.load("users.yml"));`